# How can my class be provided some information about its environment?

Tags: c++, oop, aggregation, composition, design-decisions

Here's a code sample I wrote with encapsulation and composition in mind:

```
class Bullet {
 private:
  Vector2 position;
  Vector2 speed;

 public:
  void move(float time_delta) {
    position += speed * time_delta;
  }
};
```

Basically, there's just a projectile moving in nowhere. However, a bullet can actually e. g. ricochet off a wall, having its `speed` changed significantly. Is there a good way of considering such interactions? I neither want my `Bullet` to know about "higher-rank" classes (which are supposed to use it themselves) nor write a single-use solution like this one:

```
template<typename F> void move(float time_delta, F collision_checker);
```

**UPDATE:** worth reading if you want this question narrowed. Here's a simplified example of the wished logic for moving `Bullet`s (I don't exactly mean the `Bullet::move()` member function!) and their interactions with other entities:

```
Vector2 destination = bullet.position + bullet.speed * time_delta;
if (std::optional<Creature> target = get_first_creature(bullet.position, destination)) {
  // decrease Bullet::speed depending on the target (and calculate the damage)
} else if (std::optional<Wall> obstacle = get_first_wall(bullet.position, destination)) {
  // calculate the ricochet changing Bullet::position and Bullet::speed
}
```

All pieces of code represented by comments are supposed to use some properties of the `Creature` and `Wall` `class`es.

Comment: The set of interactions with your object are defined by the class methods.

Comment: @stark it's the `Bullet` class interacting with a higher-rank one, not someone interacting with the `Bullet`.

Comment: this question cannot be answered by looking only at the bullet. As you already realized, the bullet is currently moving in nowhere without any context. One solution could be to make `move` accept an additional parameter `void move(float time_delta, World& world)` but there are too many possibilities and you should look at the bigger picture instead of considering a single class

Comment: @idclev463035818 the thing is that `World` also knows about `Bullet`, your solution gives me a circular dependency, unfortunately.

Comment: circular dependecies can be resolved, but as I already said, not by looking at only one part

Comment: @idclev463035818 which extra information does my question need to be improved enough?

Comment: i am afraid the question is just too broad. Currently you only talk about the bullet but you need to consider the bigger picture. Actually the first comment summarizes it nicely: The interactions with the object are defined by the methods. I dont know with what your bullet is supposed to interact

Comment: You could add an example of Bullet interacting with higher class.

Comment: @stark here it goes!

Comment: @idclev463035818 I've added an example, hope it's narrowing enough.

Comment: Introduce some sort of object manager. This manager has all the code that enables interaction between various objects. The manager knows if bullet is affected by gravity, or dense environment, or bullet stopping Neo character. The manager is the One.

Comment: @Dialecticus it seems like turning `Bullet` into a C-like struct (or a class with getters and setters for each field). Is there a more object-based decision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a design point of view, it is probably best if your bullet doesn't know how to detect when it's ... passing_through an obstacle (scnr). So it might be better to turn your `Bullet` class in to a `struct`, i.e. have it behave like a thing that is acted upon instead of a thing that acts.

You can still add your convenience function but have it be non-mutating:

```
struct Bullet {
  Vector2 position;
  Vector2 speed;
  Vector2 move(float time_delta) const {
    return position + speed * time_delta;
  }
};
```

This way you can compute the collisions from the calling scope:

```
auto dest = bullet.move(dt);
while (std::optional<Collision> const col = detectCollision(bullet.position,dest)) {
  bullet.position = col->intersectPoint;
  bullet.speed = col->reflectedSpeed;
  dest = col->reflectDest;
}
bullet.position = dest;
```

Here `detectCollision` checks whether the line from the bullet's current position to the new position `dest` intersects with any obstacle and computes the parameters of the reflection. Effectively you zig-zag your way to the destination that will result from all successive ping-pongs of the bullet with potential obstacles.